# Programmatically determining which horizontal DIV is currently showing

Tags: jquery, css

let's say we have a web page with horizontal panels that goes like this.

red div

green div

blue div

these are big divs, capable of covering the entire screen for most devices AND each div has a carousel so that once you are on that div, you can go sideways.

Is it possible navigate this without using a mouse?

for example:

user arrives the page.
he presses DOWN-ARROW-KEY with CTRL and the page nicely scrolls down to the GREEN DIV. And while there, he presses the RIGHT-ARROW-KEY (or the LEFT-ARROW key for that matter ) and with that, he now navigates green level horizontally. He can repeat the same actions ( that is CTRL+DOWN-ARROW-KEY and then right / left ), but now he is navigating the BLUE level.

Is there a way to determine with jQuery which div is in the current view port with jQuery?

Comment: There is a jquery plugin available for the functionality you are looking for http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Comment: That's good enough Taimur. Thank you.